# Mapping a boolean to a list in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to get a list to evaluate to a true/false against a particular number. When I define the function, clojure defines it fine. But it is not doing what I want to do. Just learning clojure... so I am not very comfortable with the syntax yet... apologies if this is a noob question.

Ideally it would take in a list like (list 9 0 3) and evaluate it to (list true false true)

```
(defn myfunc [lst](map (> x 1) lst))
```

Comment: "But it is not doing what I want to do" is not a great error description. Please make sure in further questions to also include the error message or how the result is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
(defn greater-than-one?
  [x]
  (< 1 x))
```

and then use it:

```
(mapv greater-than-one? (list 9 0 3)) => [true false true]
```

In your original format, you could also solve it like:

```
(defn myfunc [lst]
  (map #(> % 1) lst))
```

and use it:

```
(myfunc (list 9 0 3)) => (true false true)
```

---

You may find [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) helpful in getting started.  Please be sure to [see the list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) also.

Comment: Cool! Thanks! 

Also: how would you exponentiate a list?

Comment: @bl4ckh4t (map #(Math/exp %) coll)

Comment: So, say I wanted a procedure to take a list (l) and an integer (n) and return the sequence l to the power n, I could do 
(defn myfunc [x n] (map #(Math/exp % n) x))    ??

But feeding this x = (list 'a 'b) and n = 2 returns ##NaN ##NaN